# How to distribute a native Windows DLL to use with js-ctypes inside a XUL Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, dll, firefox-addon, xul, jsctypes

I have a Firefox XUL extension which makes use of a native Windows DLL using js-ctypes.

Which is the recommended way to distribute this DLL file?

I have set up a development environment just like the one that is described in the [XUL School Tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/School_tutorial), but I am not sure which modifications should I make to the directory structure and the corresponding build files (Makefile, manifest, etc) to have my DLL included into the XPI file, and then available to js-ctypes when the client uses the extension.

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you would simply zip the DLL into your XPI with the rest of your stuff and use [`em:unpack=true`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Install_Manifests#unpack), or else you won't be able to load your DLL.

Then you can use e.g. the [Add-on Manager](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/Add-on_Manager/Addon#getResourceURI%28%29) to find out where the DLL is actually installed on a user system and load it with js-ctypes.

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm");

AddonManager.getAddonByID(YOUR_ADDON_ID, function(addon) {
    //var uri = addon.getResourceURI(YOUR_RELATIVE_PATH_TO_THE_DLL);
    var uri = addon.getResourceURI("install.rdf");
    console.log("uri", uri.spec);
    if (uri instanceof Components.interfaces.nsIFileURL) {
        var file = uri.file;
        console.log("path", file.path);
    }
});
```

BTW: This stuff still works when the add-on is installed via a [proxy file](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Setting_up_extension_development_environment#Firefox_extension_proxy_file) for development purposes.